# Styled component with access to React component state?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How can I get a styled component to render different css rules depending on the state of the React component in which it is rendered?

The below does not work:

```js
class Container extends React.Component<ContainerProps, ContainerState> {
  constructor(props: ContainerProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      highlight: true,
      dark: false
    };
  }

  OuterWrapper = styled.div`
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    ${this.state.dark && `
      background-color: 'gray';
    `};
  `;

    return (
      <this.OuterWrapper>
          ...
      </this.OuterWrapper>
    );

}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark' of undefined
>       at new Container

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way to achieve that is through passing a prop to the element that you get from `styled-comopnent`.

```
// outside of the component
interface OuterWrapperProps { 
    dark: boolean; 
}

const OuterWrapper =  styled.div<OuterWrapperProps>`
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    ${props => props.dark && css`
        background-color: 'gray';
    `};
`;
```

And when you render that element:

```
...
<OuterWrapper dark={this.state.dark}> ... </OuterWrapper>
...
```

And you still have control over the theme from your `state`!

> Doing so, helps the readability of your code,  as well as following what the docs suggest.

Comment: I like that, but I get an error at the call site. [ts] Property 'dark' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<ThemedOuterStyledProps<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, any>, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'. I found this issue on the same topic https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/630 with many proposed solutions. I haven't figured out which is the best yet.

Comment: Hmm, I don't use ts. But I think if you do `${(p: ElementProps)=> props.dark ...}` with props like: `type ElementProps = { dark: boolean }`, this might get rid of the error!

Comment: Thanks! This is what I added to your answer to make it work: interface OuterWrapperProps {
  dark: boolean;
}

const OuterWrapper = styled.div<OuterWrapperProps>`
  ...
`;

Comment: Good idea! I have added to your answer.