# Using useState-hook to alter styled-components from within

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I am making a component library to use in a project of mine - I've worked quite a bit with styled-components before and it's my preferred way of applying styles to my components.  What I like best about it is the ability to make my components fully functional and self-contained.

I have one problem that I haven't really been able to solve satisfactory though.

I want to do something like this, but whatever I do I can't seem to access or set the props from within the styled-component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = ({ className }) => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <button className={className} clicked={clicked} onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}>
      {this.props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default styled(Button)`
  ${applySomeStyle}
  ${props => props.clicked} {
    ${applySomeOtherStyle}
  }
`;
```

I have been able to 'solve' it by doing this, but it seems incredibly redundant to create a dummy component just for this purpose. It would seem more natural to just be able to do what I do in example #1.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Dummy = styled.button``;

const Button = ({ className }) => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Dummy className={className} clicked={clicked} onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}>
      {this.props.children}
    </Dummy>
  );
};

export default styled(Button)`
  ${applySomeStyle}
  ${Dummy} {
     ${props => props.clicked} {
       ${applySomeOtherStyle}
     }
  }
`;
```

EDIT: The suggested linked issues are not applicable.  The first linked issue is a person essentially asking how to pass props to his child components.  The second issue is similar, but the answers are outdated because it predates the useState hook which allow us to not use Class components (The answer to the issue is basically saying that styled-components can't be used in Class components).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styled component with access to React component state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208522/styled-component-with-access-to-react-component-state)

Comment: so you want your style to access inner state rather props. it's impossible. so you need to lift state up. see also https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1746

Comment: Lifting the local state up makes the component not self-contained, it will have to rely on the parent to function properly.  It's also not impossible as it works as shown in example #2, because the style is attached to the className.  There is no reason why this shouldn't be theoretically possible when it's attached to the DOM node directly as a opposed to a dummy component representing the DOM node...  The problem discussed in the issue you link is pre-Hooks when it wasn't possible because we were using class components as opposed to functional components.

Comment: in the `<A><B/></A>`, you want `A` to have access to inner state of `B`? that is not possible without `B` exposing some API to the parent - usually a prop of `B`, but if the `B` contains a styled `Dummy` that opens a magic backdoor bypass for other styled parents of `B` to access the `Dummy` directly

Answer (score 5):

`styled()` cannot refer to inner state. It does not matter if it's class and `this.state` or function and `useState` hook. The only way to handle that is splitting component into two: first to handle state changes and another one to encapsulate changes based on props.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const InnerButton = styled(button)`
  ${props => props.clicked} {
    ${applySomeOtherStyle}
  }
`;

const Button = ({ className }) => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <InnerButton className={className} clicked={clicked} onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}>
      {this.props.children}
    </InnerButton>
  );
};

export default styled(Button)`
  ${applySomeStyle}
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the hook to conditionally set the className? Something like this...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ButtonStyled = styled('button')`
  .className {
    color: red;
}
`
export const Button = () => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <ButtonStyled className={clicked ? 'className' : ''} clicked={clicked} onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}>
      {this.props.children}
    </ButtonStyled>
)}
```

Or, if you import the `css` property from styled-components, you can do something like this....

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const ButtonStyled = styled('button')`
  ${({ clicked }) =>
    clicked &&
    css`
      color: red;
    }
`
export const Button = () => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <ButtonStyled clicked={clicked} onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}>
      {this.props.children}
    </ButtonStyled>
)}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm posting this more for my sake, it's a solution that I found sometime last year and I almost lost the project that had this trick in it.

Explanation:
So to pass a variable into css, you must use a css 'var'. Once you do this, you can use this custom variable anywhere in your css by simply entering the variables name. You can even give the variable a default value in case you fail to pass a value from your JavaScript code.

*Warning*
I use make MERN apps, which means I am doing this in React. I in no way gurantee that this will work in Angular, JQuery, pure JS or any other JavaScript variation. But it should since it's css and not JavaScript.

SOLUTION
In your JavaScript code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./Example.CSS"

export default function Example(){
    const [value, setValue] = useState('green')

    useEffect(()=>{
        document.querySelector('.example').style.setProperty('--color',value)
    },[value])

    return <div classname="example">
        <button onClick={()=>value==='green'?setValue('red'):setValue('green')}>
            Change Background Color
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

Then in your css, you can call it like this:

```
div{
    background: var(--color,'grey')
    border: var(--color)
}
```

You can add as many new key-value pairs to your JavaScript variable as you want (err, well as many as you computer and text editor can handle). If you want a default value, you can add it with a comma, otherwise, just call it normally. I am sure that I have just scratched the surface of the usage for this component but it is oddly undocumented for such a useful tool. I find this infinitely better than using inline styles.